# JQuery ajaxSubmit duplicated fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, datatables

I create a dialog (either JQUI or Bootstrap 3) and load a form via an ajax call. When the form is submitted the fields are duplicated. The form includes a DataTable and is submitted using ajaxSubmit (malsup.com)

Running this before the submit

```
var fieldList = [];    
$(formId + " input").each(function(index){  
      var input = $(this);
      fieldList.push(input.attr('name'));
});    
alert(fieldList);
var queryStr = $(formId).formSerialize();
alert(queryStr);
```

fieldList just shows a single instance for each field, but the queryStr shows each field twice.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Use `console.log(fieldList);` instead of `alert(fieldList);` because `fieldList` is an array and alert will show `zeroth index` value only. And are you using different `forms` one is having id `formId` and other is having `aFormId`?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. No just one form aFormId = "#" + formId - I'll correct the code to make it obvious (that was sloppy wasn't it?)

Comment: You should create a snippet for it, to get more close to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was simple in the end. The duplication was caused because the fields also had the formid parameter set:

```
<form id="myform">    
<input name="fieldOne" formid="myform">
</form>
```

I removed that and all was fine.